# RSpec stub helper method in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Found similar questions but surprisingly none, that I've found, give a simple answer...

Trying to stub a helper method in my controller spec; not quite sure what object would need to be doubled?

Controller calls this method:

```
#app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

def signed_in?
  current_user.present?
end
```

I'd like to stub it in spec to return true/false.

Comment: Try 'current_user.stub(:present?).and_return(true)'. I know that helper is defined somewhere else but it'll be more readable.

Comment: Alex, not a current_user.stub..., but controller.current_user.stub...

Comment: ya. `current_user.stub...` yields error: `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can stub it from the controller spec:

```
controller.stub!(:signed_in?).and_return(true) # emulate signed in user
controller.stub!(:signed_in?).and_return(false) # emulate unsigned user
```

Object 'controller' is predefined in a controller specs.

**UPDATE:**

With RSpec 3 syntax:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:signed_in?).and_return(true)
allow(controller).to receive(:signed_in?).and_return(false)
```

Thanks to @jakeonrails for reminding.

Comment: And yes, as Alex Teut wrote above, I'm usually stub both signed_in? and current_user - for my code not to depend from realization. Then spec will pass whatever method of checking I choose.

Comment: so something like `controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(FactoryGirl.create(:user))`?

Comment: Yes - to emulate signed user, or ...and_return(nil) to emulate the unsigned one. It isn't necessary, but can be useful _in_addition_ to signed_in? stabbing.

Comment: stub!, while not deprecated, should probably not be used, the better method is just `stub`: http://blog.firsthand.ca/2010/09/rspec-stub-vs-stub.html

Comment: FYI in rspec 3 for newer rails 5.2 I had to stub the controller.helpers method vs the controllers method